# My app working fine for Retina 4 inch display, problems with the 3.5 inch display

Tags: iphone, retina-display

My iphone app is working fine for a `4-inch display`, 
however it dose not display correctly to  `3.5 inch display`.

As I am a new user, I can not upload images to this question.

What happens is, when i view it on a 3.5" display. all the text boxes going here and there.

Comment: If I may, just post the images on some site, say [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/), or [dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [4shared.com](http://www.4shared.com/), and put the links in your question, so that any one having privilege can edit your post to reciprocate those images here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the problem with AutoResizing subViews.....
Please go through this tutorial.....
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling

This may help you..